# autoInc with Postgres and Slick

Tags: scala, slick

When changing from in memory database to Postgres I came across the autoInc problem with Slick and Postgres. Piecing together several sources I ended up with the following solution. This avoids providing Null to the Id column on insert and returns the inserted records id, but at the cost of repeating the fields for the table in 3 different places. Is there any way to improve this? particularly for the withoutId definition but also the insert itself requiring the fields to be listed.

```
case class Product(
  id: Option[Long], 
  name: String,
  description: String
)

object Products extends Table[Product]("products") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def description = column[Int]("description")
  def * = id.? ~ name ~ description <> (Product, Product.unapply _) // Fields listed
  def withoutId = name ~ description returning id // Fields listed again minus id

  def insert(product: Product): Product = {
    val id = DB withSession {
      withoutId.insert(product.name, product.description) // Fields listed again
    }
    product.copy(id = Option(id))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Slick 1.x, the way you did it is the way to you. You can save some boilerplate this way:

```
def columns = name ~ description
def * = id.? ~: columns <> (Product, Product.unapply _) // Fields listed
def withoutId = name ~ description returning id // Fields listed again minus id
```

In Slick 2.x the autoinc column is ignored automatically, so `.insert` should just work. For cases where you really want to insert into the autoinc column there is `.forceInsert`.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was after. It's nice to know that in the future we can clean up further with slick 2.0 too.